# View only works the first time in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app and I am utilizing routes to load two different views.

The first route `#/` is the main list view. That works every time.

My second route is `#/view/:id` and loads my second view when a list item is clicked.

The view is data driven based off the id, all of which need to make `$http` requests through a `service` I created.

Is it possible that when I leave the `#/view/:id` route, it unloads that view completely and reloads it when I come back?

**OR**

How do I go about resetting promises inside a service so that the next time the view is loaded, it will request the new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not mutually exclusive questions. Routing with `ngView` destroys the view, scope, and controller on every load, so controller and scope history are *not* preserved among routes. Otherwise, memory load in the browser would be high; instead, we can use services to preserve the state we need to across all routes.

`$http` requests are made fresh every time they are called, unless the `cache` option is enabled. There shouldn't be any work required for this to work as designed:

```js
.factory( 'dataService', function( $http ) {
  return function dataServiceFn ( id ) {
    return $http.get( '/myapi', { params: { id: id } } );
  };
});
```

When your data service is called (e.g. `dataService( $routeParams.id );` ), a new promise will be returned.

This is just a sample service structure for an incredibly simple case, but so long as the `$http` call is made fresh on each service call, you will get a new promise guaranteeing fresh data every time.

Comment: I have pretty much this exact service going on right now..it is even named `DataService`, hah. You can see it on this pastie link: http://pastie.org/7329971 So I pass a location to a file to that service, `$location` and a json file gets returned, I populate all the necessary data in my view and it looks and works great. Its when I leave and come back. The json file that got returned the first time is still the old data (oh an `$location` is a URL to json data)

Comment: I know what the problem is... `var data = []` defined in my service only gets called the first time. I think that is because of my `getData` method. I think I need to eliminate that part. I reused this service for my first view which I only wanted to load once. My second view needs to load every time so I think if I eliminate the `getData` method and just do `loadData` it should reload the data..gonna try now...

Comment: I'm fairly certain this will work, I am just having an issue now with the service where $scope.data isn't getting set. This is what I am trying to do right now http://pastie.org/7330387 my `log` is definitely showing the data is being loaded

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing and storing the data; you should store the promise that already holds the data. Then in your controller you can use `DataService.loadData().then(...)`.

Comment: alright, these services are making more sense now. So rather than setting `$scope.data = DataService.loadData()` I simply do a `DataService.loadData().then(...)` and inside the then is where I parse. I have it working now, the only thing is when I leave my `#/view/:id` I get an error in the console saying 'Uncaught reference error: player is not defined`. player referring to my video player which is pointing to my `timeupdate` event for html5 video

Comment: not really. I have a lot of dependencies and its a rather complex app. I think the error occurs because the `timeupdate` even gets fired even after the view has been removed. I need to remove the event listener when leaving that view. Is it possible to run code before leaving a view? Alternatively, I could just check if player is defined before running the code where I am getting the error

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue; I'm sure it's something basic, but without seeing the code, I would only be guessing. What is `player` and where is it defined? What's calling it?

Comment: player is inside my 2nd views controller. Its just a `<video id="player">...</video>` tag. I am looking at `$routeChangeStart` to remove the event listener on `player`

Comment: It definitely shouldn't require any crazy hacks like that. What event listener? You should use the directive's attributes as its API.

Comment: the event listener is the `timeupdate` event. I may have to rethink the way I am integrating the video player into the controller. It all works flawlessly the first time and getting all kinds of wacky problems when I come back in. I haven't used directives before, can you point me to a simple directive example that would show, say the timeupdate event? Is is not good practice to define something like `player.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){...});` inside a controller?

Answer (score 1):

Angular will unload the controller when you leave to another controller. If you need to store the data between different view, you should store it inside the service (which is not unloaded when the controller changes) or be prepared to make an $http request every time you load the view.

Comment: I am using services. Something else must be going on then that I am not aware of... most likely because I am new to angular. I wish I could post all my code, but its pretty hefty